# Will I lose anything important without online in The Last Story?

Tags: the-last-story

[Nintendo announced that they are shutting down their online for Wii and DS titles](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/info/services-update.jsp). I have a large backlog of games that I've only played briefly and I particularly dislike being tied to online features anyway because of my irregular play schedule. From what I've read, the loss of the online in The Last Story will make some online exclusive weapons and animated dyes no longer accessible. I'm not very far into the game and haven't found any guides that outline it in much detail, but is there anything that I will lose that is all that important?

- Are any of the online-exclusive weapons exceptionally powerful or noteworthy? Can I play the game and never miss them?
- Is there anything else that I will lose without online?

**What if anything is important for me to do online in this game before I lose access to it forever?**

Comment: I played the entire game and don't remember there being any online aspect to it at all... so if that is any indication, I would say you probably won't miss out on much.

Comment: If the "online-exclusive weapons" are DLC they shouldn't be affected as the Stores will remain however i'm suspicious of "Free add-on content or downloads" if this wording includes DLC

Answer (score 1):

Online, there are weapons and equipment available, that are better and more powerful then equipment you can obtain offline.

That said, you can still play and finish the game, without having played online once.

Comment: Could you rephrase a bit more clearly, please? It's not "of course" because every game is different so no assumptions. "There are weapons and equipment that are more powerful and better as offline equipment," leaves out the context of where. I think you mean to say the most powerful stuff is online, but as phrased it's not definite whether you're saying the online exclusive stuff is better or better stuff is available in the normal game. The question isn't whether I can do it all offline, but whether I'll be missing something worthwhile if I don't rush in some multiplayer before it's gone.

Comment: This answers the question, just its format is horrible